# When does := work not as an assignment operator?

Tags: delphi

In the following code := doesn't work as an assignment operator. The help says "The := symbol is sometimes called the assignment operator." I couldn't find in the help when it is not called the assignment operater.

```
procedure TForm1.TestProcedure;
var
  _Integer   , _TemporaryInteger   : Integer;
  _StringList, _TemporaryStringList: TStringList;
begin
  _Integer := 1;

  _TemporaryInteger := _Integer;

  _TemporaryInteger := 2; // doesn't change the original value that _Integer is 1

  _StringList := TStringList.Create;

  _StringList.Add('a');

  _TemporaryStringList := _StringList;

  _TemporaryStringList[0] := 'b'; // changes the original value _StringList[0] into 'b'
end;
```

Comment: You used the operator six times in that code. Which of those times are you saying it "doesn't work as an assignment operator"?

Comment: While you've got overly detailed answer already, I don't think you should leave the question in its current not very clear state for any future readers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Object Pascal **:=** is *always* an assignment operator.

The documentation wording is perhaps misleading in this respect.  It does not mean that this operator sometimes does something else, only that the operator is *sometimes referred to* as the assignment operator.

The distinction is the same as when I say that *I sometimes refer to my female parent as 'mother'*.  She is always my mother but sometimes I call her "mum" or "granny" (when talking to my children) or using her name.  But she is always my mother.  I just don't *always* refer to her using that precise term.

Also be aware that there are some occasions when assignment is achieved using a simple **=** symbol.  For example, identifying default parameter values:

```
procedure SomeUsefulProc(const aSwitch: Boolean = FALSE);
```

Also, when declaring constants or initialising global variables:

```
const
  DEFAULT_PREFIX = 'PFX';

var
  gMeaningOfLife: Integer = 42;
```

However, this does not alter the fact that **:=** is the *assignment operator*.

The assignments in these other cases **=** are not "operations" in code, but *declarations*.

### Properties vs Variables

The confusion in your question arises not from a difference in the meaning of the **:=** symbol, but rather in the fact that your first example involves a variable where-as the second involves *a property of an object*.

Objects may declare properties where the assignment of a value to a property actually calls a procedure to apply the new value.  The **TStringList** is a good example.

After adding an item to a string list, that list has an item that may be accessed using the index of that item in the **Strings** property:

```
stringList.Add('a');

// stringList.Strings[0] has the value 'a'
```

The **Strings** property is declared as the *default* property of the **TStringList** class meaning that if an "array" style index is used without any property name, then this **Strings** property will be assumed by default.

i.e. these two lines of code are exactly equivalent:

```
s := stringList.Strings[0];
s := stringList[0];
```

The **Strings** property is implemented using a function to retrieve the value of specific items (**Get**) and a procedure to modify them (**Put**).  The above lines of code are equivalent to using the **Get** function with 0 as the parameter:

```
s := stringList.Get(0);
```

Since the **Strings** property is declared with a **write** accessor then you can also write to this property, thereby calling the **Put** procedure.  To write to a property you assign a value to it, using ... the *assignment operator*.  In this case, the array index of the property is passed to the procedure along with the value to be assigned.

As before, since the **Strings** property is the default property for a stringlist, the following two lines of code are exactly equivalent:

```
stringList[0]         := 'b';
stringList.Strings[0] := 'b';
```

And in both cases the effect is to result in a call to the **write** procedure for the **Strings** property:

```
stringList.Put(0, 'b');
```

The operator is still the assignment operator and we still say that we have "assigned a value" to the property.  Assignment, in *code* (as opposed to in a *declaration*), is always performed using the assignment operator:

```
aVariable            := value;
aObject.SomeProperty := value;
```

The difference is that in the case of an object property the response to that assignment is dependent upon the implementation of the property involved.  It may simply modify some value on the object directly, or it may call a procedure to first validate the value being assigned or perform some more complex response to that property change.

In the case of a **TStringList** for example, changing an item in the list not only modifies that item but also triggers a change notification event.

### Records vs Objects (or Values vs References)

In more recent versions of Delphi you may also have properties with read/write functions implemented by **record** types.  These follow the same implementation pattern as properties on objects (i.e. **classes**).  However, in that case you will observe very different results since a **record** is a *value* type, not a *reference* type.

**NOTE:** *For the examples that follow for simplicity I am using a property that simply directly reads and writes the member rather than using Get/Set functions, but the principle is the same and also applies even if a member of an object is exposed directly (i.e. without an explicit property declaration).*

If **TMyData** is implemented as a class then the variables **a** and **b** are references to an instance of that class.  This must be explicitly created and when we assign one to the other all we are doing is creating a duplicate reference to the *same object*:

```
type
  TMyData = class
  private
    fName: String;
  public
    Age: Integer;  // Directly exposed member - effectively a read/write property
    property Name: String read fName write fName;
  end;

var
  a: TMyData;
  b: TMyData;
begin
  a := TMyDate.Create; // Create an object and store a reference in a
  try
    a.Name := 'foo';  // Set the name and age of the object we just created
    a.Age  := 42;

    b := a;           // b now also REFERENCES the same object as a
                      //  a.Name = 'foo' / Age = 42
                      //  b.Name = 'foo' / Age = 42

    b.Name := 'bar';  // We changed the Name of the object to 'bar'.  
                      //  a.Name = 'bar' / Age = 42
                      //  b.Name = 'bar' / Age = 42
                      //  a = b (they reference the same object)
  finally
    a.Free; // both a and b references are now invalid (the object has been destroyed)
end;
```

If **TMyData** is instead implemented as a *record* then a significant difference is introduced.  There is no longer any need to explicitly create or destroy objects, and when we assign values of this record type, we create copies of the value involved rather than a reference to it:

```
type
  TMyData = record
  private
    fName: String;
  public
    Age: Integer;  // Directly exposed member - effectively a read/write property
    property Name: String read fName write fName;
  end;
```

In this case if we have two variables of this type then right from the start we have two separate **TMyData** records and when we assign one to the other, we are *copying* the entire **TMyData** *value*:

```
var
  a: TMyData;
  b: TMyData;
begin
                    // a and b are both new, initialised records:
                    //   a.Name = '' / Age = 0
                    //   b.Name = '' / Age = 0

  a.Name := 'foo';  // We have set the Name and age of a.  b is unchanged
  a.Age  := 42;     //   a.Name = 'foo' / Age = 42
                    //   b.Name = ''    / Age = 0

  b := a;           // b is now a COPY of a.
                    //   a.Name = 'foo' / Age = 42
                    //   b.Name = 'foo' / Age = 42

  b.Name := 'bar';  // We changed the Name and age of b.  
  b.Age  := 84;     //   a.Name = 'foo' / Age = 42
                    //   b.Name = 'bar' / Age = 84
```

end;

Comment: thanks to your delicate, comprehensive and kind reply.

Comment: Your answer is good regarding the `:=` operator. However, it is very clear from the comments in the code, that OPs confusion stems from **value assignment** vs. **reference assignment**. Please re-read the code. In fact, there's nothing indicating a confusion with property read/write functionality.

Comment: The answer is very complete but as @TomBrunberg said, the point is not the variable assignment vs property assignment, the problem is between the value assignment vs reference assignment.  You can see that in the comments in the code.

Comment: @Tom and CrApHeR - the issue is that in the second example the assignment is to a **property** of a referenced object held in a variable.  If the assignment were to the variable itself then no confusion arises.  The assignment would change the value of the variable.  i.e. the issue is very much the involvement of a property (on the referenced object).

Comment: You have a point though in that the use of functions is not the key complication.  I shall cover this in a revision to the answer.

Answer (score 4):

In this case the variable is managed by value.

```
_TemporaryInteger := _Integer;
_TemporaryInteger := 2; // doesn't change the original value that _Integer is 1
```

When a variable is by managed by value, the variable value is copied the new variable and both are in different areas of memory.

In this case the variable is managed by reference (almost all the objects are managed by reference)

```
_TemporaryStringList := _StringList;
_TemporaryStringList[0] := 'b'; // changes the original value _StringList[0] into 'b'
```

When you have a variable managed by reference, the variable reference (pointer) is copied to the new variable and both variable are pointing to the same space of memory (because of that when you change a value in the second variable it changed in the first variables too)

Hope this helps

Comment: This answer is likely to be confusing.  The behaviour of the **:=** symbol has nothing to do with whether or not the type involved is a value type or a reference type.  In both cases it performs the appropriate assignment, either of the value or the reference.

Comment: I agree that the `:=` symbol is used for assignments, but If you see the comments in the example code, you can see why I answered in reference to the value/reference type.

Comment: As maybe, but you have misunderstood the issue in that case also.  The issue is not value types vs reference types, but properties with read/write functions.  A record (value type) in current versions of Delphi may also have properties which would exhibit the same (apparent) difference in behaviour.

Comment: The last version of Delphi I used was Delphi 7.  Maybe the versions after that supports operation overload and that is why you have different behaviors.